# WPF: How to show multiple images for preview in a list view and icon on the each image at the bottom allowing user to delete

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWPQL.png)
I want to show the images in a list view this way, I am able to show them in a list view. Please help me in how to add a icon on the image .

Below  is my code of list view  and  binding the images dynamically, Please post any sample hot to show cross mark on my image, on click event i can delete the image

Comment: what have you already tried? post some code.

Comment: In your template for your `ListViewItem` or `ListBoxItem` use `Grid` to place `<Image/>` and `Button` with custom template defined so you can use the red cross. HTH

Comment: Can you please share any sample, how to do it. My intention is to show a cross mark on the image, instead of placing a button extra

Comment: First you need to specify what is your requirement, second please share your attempt, there is a chance that you might be not far from a solution, And if you want to answer to a comment you need to tag me in by typing @ and then username, otherwise I won't know if you answered my comment.

Comment: @XAMlMAX,   I want to show an image with an icon on it, on clicking the icon, I will delete the image. for morte information plase refer to this image-   http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWPQL.png. Can you please share the sample

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I am a bit busy at work and tomorrow I have an exam, I'll give you a shout day after tomorrow with an update. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a late answer but I was really busy at work.
What you want to do is to create a `ControlTemplate` with your `Image` inside of it.
Now your `ListView` should use that template to display content like so:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ctModules}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

where your Template should look something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ctModules">
    <Grid Height="150" Width="150">
        <Image Source="{Binding url}"/>
        <Image Source="{Binding PathToYourRedCrossImage}" Width="32" Height="32" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Where Image_MouseLeftButtonDown looks like this:

```
private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //your logic here
}
```